# New design is hot, how do I get a t-shirt and stickers?

Tags: discussion

I love the new design and I'm eager to brandish a Stack Exchange t-shirt at Dreamforce, where do I signup for the goods?

Comment: I can't speak for our community team(Who does the top user swag giveaways), but typically it's soon after site graduation. Users on the first 2 pages(sorted by reputation, all time) will be receiving them. I believe they also have other plans to distribute the goods to other site contributors who are not on the top 2 pages as well.

Comment: @greenstork you made in the first 20 users in the area51 top users list :). Never knew about the top 20 users policy.

Comment: Jeez, I'm on the first two pages myself -- do I have to be at DF to get the T-shirt or will they be mailed?

Comment: @crop1645 we ship the to user swag internationally.

Comment: Yay .. !! T-shirts .. Stickers .. !! 

Comment: I already have a bespoke t-shirt I'm getting printed relevant to my session at DF, but I would also totally be proud to wear a SFSE tee during the Hands On Workshop I'm running and in general around the Dev Zone 8-) That is totally cool.

Comment: @Jin Glad you guys ship internationally, now I'm just hoping it's the first two pages on the site, not on the beta... since I didn't make the cut there!

Comment: @Jin - A lot of the people on the first 2 pages will be attending Dreamforce as well, so if it is at all possible for the community team to get shirts and stickers to them in time to be packed in luggage, I'm sure they'll all wear them.

Comment: The canonical answer: go to [this thread](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/801/dreamforce-sfse-swag) and email your details to Jin!

Answer (score 12):

Awesome stuff, was going to ask if I could get a t-shirt to wear for my Salesforce StackExchange session at DF with Matt Bingham!

If it's amenable to the StackExchange team it'd be great to get some extras to give away at the talk, so you might be able to get some there.

Comment: I just checked Dreamforce site, looks like the event is on Oct 13th. I should be able to get the T-shirts and stickers produced soon in time for that. Maybe we can get you guys some to give away at the conf to promote the site? I'll be in touch about this.

Comment: @laceysnr, Jin, possible to share some for the Salesforce Developer Groups (for ppl who won't make it to DF )

Comment: @jin that'd be great! I've done sessions for the last two years on it to help promote the site, going to be even easier to get attention now we've lost the beta label.

Comment: ++ for dug promo stuff. We've been mentioning sfse a lot in the benelux dug.

Comment: @LaceySnr sure. once we have the swag produced I can tell our vendor to ship them to wherever. just let me know the details. my email is jin@stackexchange.com

Comment: I am in for Stackexchange session at DF'14. Hope we get some awesome T-shirts and stickers during conference. :)

Comment: I promote us when at Dallas DUG meetups.

Comment: :( Sad that I wont be going this year due to project commitments . I did see you speak last time with metadaddy about stackexachange. Hopefully next time!

Comment: Has anyone received any update on the T-shirts or stickers? We're now nearly 4 weeks away from #DF14 so I'm hoping it's shipped soon or else it won't be in time for the conference :(

Answer (score 4):

+1 - I too have a session focused around community learning on Salesforce at Dreamforce 2014 (precisely on the opening day of the conference - 13th October) and Salesforce StackExchange will be a key part of it. Hope to get one in time for the conference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several sites on the web, where you can create/design your own shirts.

Only problem, is that you need to have the rights to use the design.

I don't think we have these rights.

I did play with one (made an iphone 5 case :-)  )

http://www.spreadshirt.net/design-your-own-t-shirt-C59/product/123088645/view/1/sb/l

Another site is [www.zazzle.com](http://www.zazzle.com)

If we can use the images, that will be [awsome](http://www.ted.com/talks/jill_shargaa_please_please_people_let_s_put_the_awe_back_in_awesome).